# How to get scale works cross-browser in center position on SVG elements with CSS

Tags: css, svg, cross-browser, scale, css-transforms

I have some SVG elements, which should be scaled on hover (see the attached code snippet below please). It works well on WebKit browsers (adding `transform-origin: 50% 50%;` to `g` element did the job). But Firefox seems to scale it in own way (like need to get some extra `translate(x,y)` and Edge doesn't scale it at all. What are your suggestions? Am I doing it wrong or should use a separate styling for different browser engines? I would like to solve it with CSS however, this is just an example. There are more g elements to be scaled with different x and y positions.

```css
g {
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

g:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<svg height="260px" width="1106px" viewBox="0 0 1106 260">
  <g><rect fill="#ffffff" height="13" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="#b3b3b3" stroke-width="1" width="30" x="20" y="78.5"></rect><text fill="#999999" font-family="Verdana" font-size="9" x="25" y="88.5">REC</text></g>
  <g><rect fill="#ffffff" height="13" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="#b3b3b3" stroke-width="1" width="30" x="32.5" y="128.5"></rect><text fill="#999999" font-family="Verdana" font-size="9" x="37.5" y="138.5">REC</text></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: try to wrap your SVG inside a div and just scale the container. Applying some transformation to a SVG in firefox made me crazy too.

Comment: @fcalderan these rectangles are inside one `SVG` tag, so wrapping the whole SVG to separately scale `g` elements inside, doesn't make sense. Also wrapping `g` with `div` broke the code.

Answer (score 1):

You've assumed the transform-box is the fill-box, it's not by default it's the view-box. I've adjusted the box model to match your expectations below.

```css
g {
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-box: fill-box;
}

g:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<svg height="260px" width="1106px" viewBox="0 0 1106 260">
  <g><rect fill="#ffffff" height="13" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="#b3b3b3" stroke-width="1" width="30" x="20" y="78.5"></rect><text fill="#999999" font-family="Verdana" font-size="9" x="25" y="88.5">REC</text></g>
  <g><rect fill="#ffffff" height="13" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="#b3b3b3" stroke-width="1" width="30" x="32.5" y="128.5"></rect><text fill="#999999" font-family="Verdana" font-size="9" x="37.5" y="138.5">REC</text></g>
</svg>
```

```css
g {
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

g:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<svg height="260px" width="1106px" viewBox="0 0 1106 260">
  <g><rect fill="#ffffff" height="13" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="#b3b3b3" stroke-width="1" width="30" x="20" y="78.5"></rect><text fill="#999999" font-family="Verdana" font-size="9" x="25" y="88.5">REC</text></g>
  <g><rect fill="#ffffff" height="13" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="#b3b3b3" stroke-width="1" width="30" x="32.5" y="128.5"></rect><text fill="#999999" font-family="Verdana" font-size="9" x="37.5" y="138.5">REC</text></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it solves my problem partially (according to [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box) it is quite new stuff and covers FF55+) but at least on Edge, there is no weird on hover behavior, so happy to get this improved on new FF browsers :). Is there anything you can suggest to prevent bad scaling on FF versions which doesn't support  `transform-box`?

Comment: edit about:config and set svg.transform-box.enabled, or alternatively rewrite everything so you use the view-box

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but enabling it in the browser it's good just for tests, but from the users' point of view, it is useless. The question is how to rewrite it to viewbox properly, keeping in mind, that the view box is generated, so might change as well as the position of scaled elements.